# Unpacked array- Incompatible complex type

Tags: system-verilog

I need some help.

I am trying to count the number of ones in unpacked array.

Below are the codes.

```
module test_rand;
  bit [7:0] mask_unpacked [0:7];
  int  numOnes[0:7];
    initial begin
      mask_unpacked[0] = 8'b00001111;
      mask_unpacked[1] = 8'b00001111;
      mask_unpacked[2] = 8'b00000000;
      mask_unpacked[3] = 8'b00000000;
      mask_unpacked[4] = 8'b00000000;
      mask_unpacked[5] = 8'b00000000;
      mask_unpacked[6] = 8'b00000000;
      mask_unpacked[7] = 8'b00000000;
      $display("*********************************");
      foreach (mask_unpacked[i]) begin
        $display("mask_unpacked   = %p",mask_unpacked[i]);
        numOnes= $countones(mask_unpacked[i]);
        $display("countones = %p", numOnes[i]);
      end
      $display("*********************************");
    end
endmodule
```

But, I got error message

```
Error-[ICTA] Incompatible complex type
testbench.sv, 16
  Incompatible complex type assignment
  Type of source expression is incompatible with type of target expression. 
  Mismatching types cannot be used in assignments, initializations and 
  instantiations. The type of the target is 'int$[0:7]', while the type of the
  source is 'int'.
  Source Expression: $countones(mask_unpacked[i])
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to write:

```
numOnes[i]= $countones(mask_unpacked[i]);
```

But if you want the *total* number of ones in the whole unpacked array, you would write:

```
module test_rand;
  bit [7:0] mask_unpacked [8];
  int  numOnes;
    initial begin
      mask_unpacked[0] = 8'b00001111;
      mask_unpacked[1] = 8'b00001111;
      mask_unpacked[2] = 8'b00000000;
      mask_unpacked[3] = 8'b00000000;
      mask_unpacked[4] = 8'b00000000;
      mask_unpacked[5] = 8'b00000000;
      mask_unpacked[6] = 8'b00000000;
      mask_unpacked[7] = 8'b00000000;
      numOnes = mask_unpacked.sum() with ($countones(item));
      $display("countones = %d", numOnes);
    end
endmodule
```